# How to edit listview item and save by click another listitem

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the requirement to edit the list item by tapping the list item.so when i click the list item textview should be turn into a edittext box.but when i have to select the other list item then first clickable list item should be updated there.And  corresponding list item will open the edittext in same place of list item.so can any one suggest me how to click second list/third list item to hide the edittext of first list item.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom adapter , inside this make a custom view .

custom view will contain : textview & edittextview .

initially :  textView ( visibility : visible ), EditTextView ( visibility : hidden ) .
when ever you click into any element : textView ( visibility : hidden ), EditTextView ( visibility : visible ) .

you can perform this in : getView by , implementing method , there with a clicked position item .